# Java cannot find symbol error by setting defaults

Tags: java

Trying to enter a while loop that allows users to enter numbers and operators. I am trying to set any default value like `char operator = x;` to get into the loop itself but I keep getting cannot find symbol error. What am I doing wrong?

```
  BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
  String inputValues;

  // Sets the variable defaults
  double accumulator = 0;
  double newVal;
  char operator = x;             // Here is where I get my error

  // Create the loop here
  while (operator != 't' && operator != 'T') {

     // Takes user input values here
     inputValues = input.readLine();
     String[] inputValue = inputValues.split("\\s+");

     // Sets accumulator number and operator value
     accumulator = Double.parseDouble(inputValue[0]);
     operator = inputValue[1].charAt(0);
```

Comment: What is x . There is no such variable . You might be doing `char operator = 'x';`

Comment: Your `while` condition is incorrect. You should be checking for OR, not AND. A simpler approach to avoid this would be to use `Character.toUpperCase(operator) != 'T'`

Answer (score 2):

That's not how you set a `char`. You need to use single quotes.

```
char operator = 'x';
```

You should consider taking a look at the Java docs on primitive types: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

Comment: thanks. I will accept answer here in 8 min

Comment: @MarcusBurkhart I believe you :)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to set the `operator` variable to the character `'x'`, then you must provide single quotes, else the compiler will think `x` is a variable.

If you expect `x` to be another variable, then you must define it and set a value.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you want to initialize variable operator with character 'x'

So this is the correct way to Initialize it

```
char operator = 'x';
```

Double quotes are for string literals, e.g.:

```
String str= "Hello world";
```

Single quotes are for single character literals, e.g.:

```
char c = 'x';
```